# Given that $\triangle ABC$ is right triangle, $[AB]\perp [BC]$ , $[AD]$ is bisector, $|DC| = 4, |BD| = 2$, Find the side $|AC| = x$

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFprv.jpg)

Given that $\triangle ABC$ is right triangle, $[AB]\perp [BC]$ ,  $[AD]$ is bisector, $|DC| = 4, |BD| = 2$, Find the side $|AC| = x$

**My work and research:**

We know that an angle bisector of an angle of a triangle divides the opposite side in two segments that are proportional to the other two sides of the triangle. However, I noticed that let's give $|BD|  = x$, then $|DC| = 2x$. So, I'm out of my mind right now.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! $x$ is supposed to  be $|AD|$…

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, am too grateful! Why?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @Bernard Also can you give more clear hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\frac{2}{4}=\frac{c}{x}$$ and $$c^2+36=x^2$$ so $$\frac{1}{4}x^2+36=x^2$$

Comment: Why $\frac{1}{4}x^2$ instead of $c^2$?

Comment: From our first equation we get $$c=\frac{1}{2}x$$

Comment: This is from the bissectrix theorem

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Determine $|AB|$ in function of $|AC|$, and apply Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: Then we should have the special triangle $6 - 8 - 10$ For the triangle $\triangle ABC$, we have $|BC| = 6$

Comment: I can't determine $|AB|$.

Comment: In function of $|AC|$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: You  can  determine $|AB|$  as a function of $x$ with  the *bissectrix theorem* you  mentioned in your post.